# How does the Selenium Grid2 load balancing method works?

Tags: load-balancing, selenium-grid2

I'm using Selenium Grid2 for executing Selenium Scripts remotely.

Is anyone aware if the Grid2 Hub actually load-balance the workload?

For instance... I have a Grid Hub with 2 registered Nodes, both registered with the same capacities (5 firefox, 5 chrome). What I'm seeing is that all tests are being directed to the first registered node, even if the second node has no work at all.

Does this means that only after a node is at it's full capacity, then the Hub will redirect the job to the second node, and so on?

Thanks and Regards,
Rodrigo.